# Unmet dependencies error on terminal

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Hello guys i am trying to install macubuntu theme on my linux and i proceeded with the following command: `sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7`

I received the following error:

> ```
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7 : Depends: gtk2-engines-pixbuf but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

I tried to resolve it by installing the required packages by  this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

But now i get this error:

> ```
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  gtk2-engines-pixbuf : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.30-1ubuntu1) but 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

I can't proceed further now. Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT: output of `apt-cache policy gtk2-engines-pixbuf`

```
gtk2-engines-pixbuf:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1
Version table:
     2.24.30-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

EDIT 2: Sources list:

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial restricted multiverse universe main
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

etc/apt/sources.list.d:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudfoundry-cli.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/damien-moore-ubuntu-codeblocks-stable-xenial.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/damien-moore-ubuntu-codeblocks-stable-xenial.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-xenial.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-xenial.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docky-core-ubuntu-stable-xenial.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docky-core-ubuntu-stable-xenial.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-xenial.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-xenial.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-themes-xenial.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-themes-xenial.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-tor-browser-xenial.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-tor-browser-xenial.list.save
```

Comment: Try running `apt-get update` first and then try to install again

Comment: I have done that... did not work

Comment: Are you sure that `macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7` is compatible with your Ubuntu version? From where you got this package?

Comment: yeah i m using 16.04 lts version and it is compatible with this version

Comment: @fkraiem i have updated the result of apt-cache policy gtk2-engines-pixbuf
Plz have a look

Comment: Can u tell how to do that

Comment: I have not tried to change it previously...

Comment: You have very many files, we need to find the one where `xenial-updates/main` is enabled; please provide the ouput of `grep xenial-updates /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Comment: Make sure that "xenial-updates" is enabled in *Software & Updates -> Updates* and run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The thing is, it seems to be enabled for `main` but not for `universe`...

Comment: @fkraiem: Good catch; might explain the confusion.

Comment: @fkraiem: OTOH, the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` indicates that my suggestion would make a difference. *Software & Updates* would add the necessary stuff to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson  thanks a lot.... yeah xenials-update were not enabled... it is working now... u made my day :)

Comment: @fkraiem thanks a lot for giving your valuable tym :)

Comment: Great that you made it work. In that case, if you didn't already do so, you should also enable `xenial-security`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7` depends on `gtk2-engines-pixbuf`, which in turn depends on `libgtk2.0-0`, and furthermore it is imperative that `gtk2-engines-pixbuf` and `libgtk2.0-0` are kept at the same version.

For reasons that are still unclear, your system wanted to install version `2.24.30-1ubuntu1` of `gtk2-engines-pixbuf` and version `2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2` of `libgtk2.0-0`. Since `2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2` is a higher version than `2.24.30-1ubuntu1`, both packages should be at version `2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2`, but as shown by `apt-cache policy gtk2-engines-pixbuf`, you did not have a repository providing version `2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2` of `gtk2-engines-pixbuf`.

Per [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/gtk2-engines-pixbuf), this version is available in `xenial-updates/universe`, so this section of the archive should be enabled, for example by enabling *xenial-updates* in *Software & Updates → Updates*.